# Total multiplicity and entropy of Einstein solids

Tags: thermodynamics

This is really a question to get a little more insight about a homework exercise.

***1.*** In my text book, the sum of multiplicities for all possible macrostates is given to be:

$$\sum \Omega_\mathrm{total}=\binom{N_A+N_B+q_\mathrm{total}-1}{q_\mathrm{total}}$$

For two Einstein solids $A$ and $B$ of $N_A$ oscillators in solid $A$, $N_B$ oscillators in solid $B$ and $q_\mathrm{total}$ units of energy in the system. I tried deriving this myself (which the text book doesn't require) but no dice there. How can I derive this myself?

---

***2.*** The problem here is that the followup question pretty much defines the long term entropy of this system to be:

$$S=k\ln\left(\sum\Omega_\mathrm{total}\right)$$

Now there's confusion. I simply have no idea what I'm doing. Why is the sum of all the multiplicities together the long term entropy? How should I reason that this is the correct answer? Some explanation would be very, *very* welcome.

Comment: Are you aware that $S=k_B\ln \Omega$ is in fact the *usual* way to define entropy? What's throwing you off there?

Comment: What's throwing me off is the difference between the entropy of the most likely macrostate and this. Why is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I will not derive this exact formula for you, but instead show you the derivation for a single solid (following Schroeder's 'Introduction to thermal physics', where I learned it). The generalization to two solids is then very simple (mostly a conceptual difference; the math hardly changes).

   Consider an Einstein solid with $N$ oscillators and $q$ units of energy. The problem of calculating the multiplicity can be visualized as follows Given $N-1$ vertical lines - representing partitions between different oscillators - and $q$ dots - representing units of energy - how many ways are there of arranging these symbols? This problem is quite simple: There are a total of $q+N-1$ symbols, and one just has to pick the location of the $q$ dots (or, equivalently, the $N-1$ lines) to uniquely specify an arrangement. Thus, there must be
   $$ \Omega=\binom{N+q-1}{q}$$ different arrangements corresponding to the same macrostate.
2. I will continue to consider a single solid, which is qualitatively the same thing. One considers a solid, about which is only known that it consists of $N$ oscillators, sharing $q$ units of energy. This specifies the macrostate. Given that the system is in some macrostate, the entropy is $$S=k_B\ln \Omega$$ where $\Omega$ is the number of microstates corresponding to that particular macrostate.

---

**About long term and short term entropy:**

Consider a system like the one you are asking about - where two subsystems share a fixed amount of energy. Then, one can say that on any practical timescales, the total system will be in the entropy- (and therefore multiplicity-)maximizing configuration. Denoting the corresponding multiplicity by $\Omega_1$, we can define the 'short term entropy' as $S=k_B\ln\Omega_1$. This is really the most practically useful concept of entropy, and therefore the prefix 'short term' is often dropped.

However, if we leave the system for *extremely* long times, one can say that, since all microstates are probed, we eventually lose *any* knowledge of the state of the system - it could be in *any* state. Therefore, one can define the 'long term entropy', which is defined as $S_\text{long}=k_B\ln\left(\sum_{\text{macrostates}}\Omega\right)$, i.e. one uses the *total* multiplicity, which sums over all possible states.

Comment: In regards to (1), I believe what I was looking for is the Vandermonde identity. For (2): could you include the difference between the multiplicity over short and long time scales ? For the short time scale, the most likely probability has a corresponding combined multiplicity which is not equal to the long term total multiplicity. I don't see how that can be the case.